# Getting a comma seperated list from a linq projection

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

```
    var users = from u in db.Users.Include("UserLogins")
      join ul in db.UserLogins on u.UserId equals ul.UserId
      join ua in db.UserActions ON ul.UserLoginId = ua.UserLoginId
      where u.IsActive = true
      group new { ul, ua }
        by new {u.UserId} into proj

    select new 
    {
    UserId = (Int32)y.Key.UserId,
        LoginDates = ????????
    };
```

Is it possible to return either a collection of dates List in the projection?

I'm guessing not, how about a comma seperated list of dates?

Something like:

```
"DateTime1, Datetime2, DateTime3"
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you want to do here...

Comment: Are DateTime1, 2, 3 the values in the group?

Comment: The datetime values are coming from the ul join table (UserLogins).

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm understanding your question correctly...

```
var users =
  from u in db.Users
  where u.IsActive
  select new
  {
    u.UserId,
    LoginDates =
      from d in u.LoginDates
      select d.LoginDate,
  };
```

This will make `LoginDates` an `IEnumerable` of whatever type `LoginDate` is (probably `IEnumerable<DateTime>`). You can create a comma-separated list from that, if you like, afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to return either a collection of dates List in the projection?

Sure, each grouping implements `IEnumerable` so you could just use `ToList`:

```
select new 
{
    UserId = (Int32)y.Key.UserId,
    LoginDates = y.Select( i => i.LoginDate).ToList()
};
```

> how about a comma seperated list of dates?

Just use [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx):

```
var users = (from u in db.Users.Include("UserLogins")
  join ul in db.UserLogins on u.UserId equals ul.UserId
  join ua in db.UserActions ON ul.UserLoginId = ua.UserLoginId
  where u.IsActive = true
  group new { ul, ua }
    by new {u.UserId} into proj)
.AsEnumerable()  // Hydrate the query
.Select(y=> new 
{
    UserId = (Int32)y.Key.UserId,
    LoginDates = string.Join(",",
                             y.Select( i => i.LoginDate
                                             .ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                                     ).ToArray()
                            )
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that will work, I was getting this error when I tried string.join LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join....method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: You'll need to call `AsEnumerable` or `ToList` to hydrate the query before calling `Join`.  See my updated answer

Comment: Could also do `y.Select(i=> i.LoginDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")).Aggregate((curr, next) => curr + ", " + next)`